# Cantonese Pronunciation of 户珥 (Hur)

Tags: pronunciation, cantonese

Hur ([Ex. 17:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ex%2017%3A12&version=ESV;CUVMPT;CNVT)) in the Bible is translated as [户珥](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%B7%E7%8F%A5). Does anybody know for sure how to pronounce 户珥 in Cantonese?

珥 has [two variants](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-can/search.php?q=%D2%AD) (Jyutping)

> nei6 餌, 鈮, 膩

and

> ji6 二, 樲, 潩

I just wonder which one should be used for 户珥. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image: pronunciation]

> Woo6-yi5
>
> 户珥

From this [pdf](http://download.jw.org/files/media_magazines/69/w_f-lp-2_e-Csl_CHS_20140215.pdf) pg. 14 户珥 is pronounced Woo6-yi5 (Jyutping should be something like: Wu6-ji5).

Answer (score 0):

There is an on-line audio version of the Cantonese bible. This chapter is at 
https://wordproject.org/bibles/big5/02/17.htm
I think I heard ji6, but I was pretty lost at the end.